# Python test a method with a mocked class

Tags: python, mocking

I'm writing a unit test for a method `MyClass.validate`:

```
def validate(self, x):
    if x > self.y:
        return True
```

I would like to mock out `MyClass` s.t. I can set the `y` attr to a value (e.g. 42), but then still be able to call `MyClass.validate`. How? I've gone through many magic mock and patch blog posts and SO questions, but none seem to address this use case. For example, I can do

```
@mock.patch('path.to.my_class.MyClass')
def create_mock_class(MockMyClass):
    MockMyClass.y = 42
    return MockMyClass

mock_class = create_mock_class()
```

But `mock_class.validate` is an unusable MagicMock. I'd like to be able to call e.g. `assert mock_class.validate(55)` in my unit test.

Comment: It's not clear why you would need a mock here. Just set the value of `MyClass.y` before the test, and (if necessary) restore the original value after.

Comment: I need to mock out the class because it's not possible (not to mention poor unit test form) to create a full instance of the class in the test harness.

Comment: Why can't you instantiate `MyClass` in your unittest? It is not bad form to instantiate classes in unittests.

Comment: Also, how would instantiating your class be any different from instantiating a `Mock` object? If you are concerned about how *much* work would be done by instantiating your class, it might be a sign that you are doing too much work in the initializer, work that could be deferred until later.

Comment: There are many scenarios where you wouldn't want to init a class in order to unit test a method. Perhaps `MyClass` implements some functionality and publishes messages to some external clients (e.g. ROS topics), and the initialization of `MyClass` establishes the network connections. We just want to unit test the implemented functionality without having to establish the messaging protocol. In some cases we could refactor the constructor to avoid this, but sometimes that's non-trivial or impossible (e.g. if `MyClass` is an external module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using the mock module:

```
class MockMyClass(MyClass):
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y

mock_class = MockMyClass(42)
assert mock_class.validate(55)
```

where `MyClass.validate` is called, which internally uses the instance's `y` attr.

This achieves the objective b/c the `MyClass` constructor is never called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mock.patch.object`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch-object)

```
myclass = MyClass()

with mock.patch.object(myclass, 'y', new=42):
    assert myclass.validate(55)
```

This will only patch that one attribute, and all the other functions on the class will be the original.

Comment: Thanks I've tried this approach but for some reason get ` AttributeError: <class 'path.to.my_class.MyClass'> does not have the attribute 'y'`

Comment: `y` must be an instance attribute.  I've updated the answer for that scenario.

Comment: You've now edited from `with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'y', new=42):`, which I can't do because I can't create an instance of the class.

Comment: How do you expect to test a function on the class, without creating an instance of the class?  You'll need to provide more information for *why* you can't create an instance of the class.  You may be able to use mocks to handle whatever external effects you're worried about.

Comment: ... hence this question